# ESP8266 Point to Point communication with 2 arduinos

Tags: arduino, hardware, wireless, esp8266

I am using 2 esp8266 wireless modules to establish bidirectional wireless communication between 2 arduino boards (one mega and one uno) without the use of any earth based technologies (i.e. radio frequencies, wifi which relies on earth sattelites, etc.). My solution was to use the esp8266 to establish a private area network with both esp's acting as a station and an access point (AT+CIPMODE=3). Unfortunately, this solution has proven to be more of a hassle than it was worth.

To start, I have the esp's each wired according to this diagram
[image: Arduino Wiring]
When I first started out, the red LED was on and the blue LED was off. During this time, I was able to send AT commands, establish the server, and achieve the communication I required by entering commands directly to the serial monitor. After this, I started writing a library using the SoftwareSerial library to allow me to issue commands directly through the program to set up the esp as needed upon start up of my script. Before doing this, I changed the baudrate to make sure it was running at 9600, and entered the AT commands in the serial monitor to make sure everything was working properly and it still worked.
After I began writing the library, before uploading the code with a test of the library I noticed the blue LED was lit solid now. Noticing this, I reuploaded the barebones script (I haven't uploaded the library code to the arduino yet) and the esp was no longer receiving the AT commands.

Does this indicate an issue with the board which I can fix or does this mean the board is done?

With my deadlines approaching fast in about 3 weeks it is crucial I get this wireless communication working so if this is an issue with the board, I'm going to have to scrap the esp's and use a different way of communicating. So my second question is, if this is the case, what are other viable options for establishing this communication? I have used xbee's before and while that would be ideal, they fall out of the budget I have been alotted so I need to keep it under $50 for this. If bidirectional communication is not possible for that price I can live with one way because I just need to get this system working. Basically I just need to transmit a single byte of data.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this response is a little belated, and I hope you got it sorted: I've started working with the ESP8266 myself in the last few weeks, and hence why I was looking around for tutorials on direct communication between 2 units, when I found your post.

From what I've been able to ascertain, the AT commands are a part of the 'firmware' which ships with some modules. The Arduino code however starts loading onto the chips at memory address 0x0000, which is the same address that the firmware update tools use.

In other words, I believe that with the Arduino-coded program running on there, you lose the AT command functionality.

If you find a firmware update tool for the ESP8266 (plenty online) you'll get back the AT commands.

I suppose though the real question is why would you want to? It seems that the AT commands are just a way to treat the ESP as a dumb WiFi antenna. With the Arduino code, you're actually treating it as a micro-controller in its own right.